# How do I convert EBCDIC to TEXT using Hadoop Mapreduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, ebcdic, recordreader

I need to parse an EBCDIC input file format. Using Java, I am able to read it like below:

```
InputStreamReader rdr = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("/Users/rr/Documents/workspace/EBCDIC_TO_ASCII/ebcdic.txt"), java.nio.charset.Charset.forName("ibm500"));
```

But in Hadoop Mapreduce, I need to parse via `RecordReader` which has not worked so far.

Can any one provide a solution to this problem?

Comment: You need to convert it to ASCII, and you're already doing that. Your question remains obscure.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to parse it through Spark, maybe, by using [Cobrix](https://github.com/AbsaOSS/cobrix) which is an open-source COBOL data source for Spark.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do is to convert data to ASCII first and then load to HDFS.

Answer (score 0):

Why is the file in **EBCDIC** ???, does it need to be ???

If it is just **Text** data, why not convert it to **ascii** when you **send / pull** the file from the Mainframe / AS400 ???.

If the file contains binary or Cobol numeric fields then you have several options

1. Convert the file to normal Text on the mainframe (The Mainframe Sort utility is good at this), then send the file and convert it (to ascii) .
2. If it is a Cobol file, There are some open source projects you could look at https://github.com/tmalaska/CopybookInputFormat or https://github.com/ianbuss/CopybookHadoop
3. There are commercial packages for loading mainframe-Cobol data into hadoop.